# Trouble with three operators

Tags: java, operators

The question is about my if statement.  I am comparing three values that are all of the same type, but I get an error likes this "The argument type == is undefined for types boolean,int"  The thing is, if I change my code to compare the values separately using &&.. so value == value1 && value = value2, I don't get an error.  What is the difference?

```
Card[] cardsIn = cards;
    boolean threeOfAKindEval = false;
    //the for loops runs through every possible combination of the 5 card array.  It starts at
    //0,0,0 and ends at 5,5,5/  Inside  the last for loop, I check for a three of a kind
    //My if statement also checks to make sure I am not comparing the same card with
    //itself three times 
    for(int index = 0; index < cards.length; index++){
        for(int indexCheck = 0; indexCheck < cards.length;indexCheck++){
            for(int indexCheckThree = 0; indexCheckThree < cards.length; 
                    indexCheckThree++){
                if(cardsIn[index].getValue() == cardsIn[indexCheck].getValue()  == cardsIn[indexCheckThree].getValue())
                    threeOfAKindEval = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` compares two arguments of the same type and returns a boolean result.

```
  cardsIn[index].getValue() == cardsIn[indexCheck].getValue()  == cardsIn[indexCheckThree].getValue())
```

is evaluated as

```
  bool temporalBool = cardsIn[indexCheck].getValue()  == cardsIn[indexCheckThree].getValue())
  bool finalBool = cardsIn[indexCheck].getValue()  == temporalBool // <-- left side int, right side bool
```

The `&&` operator does the logical AND of boolean types, so it is what you need.

```
 cardsIn[index].getValue() == cardsIn[indexCheck].getValue()  && cardsIn[index].getValue() == cardsIn[indexCheckThree].getValue()
```

is evaluated as

```
 bool temporalBool1 = cardsIn[index].getValue() == cardsIn[indexCheckThree].getValue()
 bool temporalBool2 = cardsIn[index].getValue() == cardsIn[indexCheck].getValue()  
 bool result = temporalBool1 && temporalBool2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code require to modify here as foolows:

```
if(cardsIn[index].getValue() == cardsIn[indexCheck].getValue() &&  cardsIn[index].getValue()  == cardsIn[indexCheckThree].getValue())
```

Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

Your code require to modify here as foolows:

```
if(cardsIn[index].getValue() == cardsIn[indexCheck].getValue() &&  cardsIn[index].getValue()  == cardsIn[indexCheckThree].getValue())
```

Now it should work

in your code

```
if(cardsIn[index].getValue() == cardsIn[indexCheck].getValue()  == cardsIn[indexCheckThree].getValue())
```

First comparison return a Boolean value `(true/false)` and again its compare that boolean with an integer value that why you are getting this error